# internet very slow speedtest fails with socket errors

Tags: networking, wireless, internet, download-speed, sockets

We changed ISP's recently, & I notice that the ubuntu computer is having a lot of difficulty now with the internet. It frequenly hangs in the middle of a download.

When I visit speedtest.net on a wired windows box I get download speeds of 100MB/s.

A wireless android tablet gives 10MB/s.

When I try the same with the ubuntu laptop, It frequently hangs and reports a socket error.

I installed speedtest-cli & an seeing results like below.

service network-manager restart usually fixes it, but I don't know why it hangs.

Any advice would be appreciated

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

```
$ speedtest-cli

Retrieving speedtest.net configuration...

Testing from TWC (now Spectrum) (97.99.67.127)...

Retrieving speedtest.net server list...

Selecting best server based on ping...

Hosted by  [23.66 km]: 24.126 ms

Testing download speed........

Download: 6.31 Mbit/s

Testing upload speed................

Upload: 0.00 Mbit/s

$ speedtest-cli

Retrieving speedtest.net configuration...

Cannot retrieve speedtest configuration

ERROR: urlopen error [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution
```

~~~~~~~~~~~~

$ ifconfig

```
eno1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr d4:be:d9:16:b0:26  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:20 Memory:e2e00000-e2e20000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:113642 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:113642 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:10046445 (10.0 MB)  TX bytes:10046445 (10.0 MB)

wlp2s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 24:77:03:3b:3c:4c  
          inet addr:192.168.0.10  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::ea11:22f4:8e44:76e5/64 Scope:Link
          inet6 addr: 2605:6001:e167:6700:5dae:8526:4231:5282/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: 2605:6001:e167:6700:7c7a:e8d1:4d11:f74a/64 Scope:Global
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1153546 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:765597 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
```

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

sudo lshw -C network

```
 *-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 19
       bus info: pci@0000:00:19.0
       logical name: eno1
       version: 04
       serial: d4:be:d9:16:b0:26
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation

       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k firmware=0.13-3 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair

       resources: irq:28 memory:e2e00000-e2e1ffff memory:e2e80000-e2e80fff ioport:4080(size=32)

  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Centrino Ultimate-N 6300
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlp2s0
       version: 35
       serial: 24:77:03:3b:3c:4c
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet 
physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.4.0-81-

generic firmware=9.221.4.1 build 25532 ip=192.168.0.10 latency=0 link=yes 

multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abgn
       resources: irq:29 memory:e2d00000-e2d01fff

          RX bytes:1293352701 (1.2 GB)  TX bytes:136286156 (136.2 MB)
```

~~~~~wired~~~~~~

sudo lshw -C network

```
  *-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 19
       bus info: pci@0000:00:19.0
       logical name: eno1
       version: 04
       serial: d4:be:d9:16:b0:26
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k duplex=full firmware=0.13-3 ip=192.168.0.9 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:28 memory:e2e00000-e2e1ffff memory:e2e80000-e2e80fff ioport:4080(size=32)
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Centrino Ultimate-N 6300
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlp2s0
       version: 35
       serial: 24:77:03:3b:3c:4c
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.4.0-81-generic firmware=9.221.4.1 build 25532 ip=192.168.0.10 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abgn
       resources: irq:29 memory:e2d00000-e2d01fff
```

~~~~~wired~~~~~

$ ifconfig

```
eno1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr d4:be:d9:16:b0:26  
          inet addr:192.168.0.9  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: 2605:6001:e167:6700:4ca3:18de:cd85:9ba7/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: fe80::c80f:aaa4:7183:e5b5/64 Scope:Link
          inet6 addr: 2605:6001:e167:6700:4bbc:d3c4:e746:a6dd/64 Scope:Global
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:321 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:348 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:77840 (77.8 KB)  TX bytes:58218 (58.2 KB)
          Interrupt:20 Memory:e2e00000-e2e20000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:114936 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:114936 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:10157001 (10.1 MB)  TX bytes:10157001 (10.1 MB)

wlp2s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 24:77:03:3b:3c:4c  
          inet addr:192.168.0.10  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::ea11:22f4:8e44:76e5/64 Scope:Link
          inet6 addr: 2605:6001:e167:6700:5dae:8526:4231:5282/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: 2605:6001:e167:6700:7c7a:e8d1:4d11:f74a/64 Scope:Global
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1155782 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:767395 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:1294160759 (1.2 GB)  TX bytes:136590978 (136.5 MB)
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61294/discussion-on-question-by-bob-mounger-internet-very-slow-speedtest-fails-with-so).

Comment: I am having this same issue with debian linux 9, in 2018. Did you ever determine the cause? What kernel version do you have? for me uname -a reports Linux <hostname> 4.9.0-6-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.88-1+deb9u1 (2018-05-07) x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: You and I have the e1000e kernel module in common.